# How to conditionally load CSS and extend it using SASS/SCSS

Tags: css, sass

**tl:dr version:** is there a way to @extend a css class and not have the original class appear in my compiled css *without* changing all my css classes to %placeholder classes?

**Short answer based on the below answers**: it appears there is no way to do this unless you go through and convert the css to silent/placeholder classes e.g. convert .one{} to %one{} and even then that will cause problems with media queries.

I have a css file (lets call it "style.css") which contains 200+ CSS classes to style various elements like forms and buttons etc. What I want is to include some of those classes in a project and other classes from that file in other random projects/websites. With each new project I also want to give the classes random semantic class names of my choosing.

My preprocessor of choice when working with CSS is SCSS and I really need an answer that uses the power of SCSS.

Here is a quick example of what I'm talking about - loading css into a SCSS file and then extending that css with my own class names:

```
//style.css
.one {
  color: red;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

//style2.scss
@import "style.css";

.two {
  @extend .one;
}
```

The problem here is that my SCSS file will compile to CSS and look like this:

```
//style2.css
.one {
  color: red;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
.two {
  color: red;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
```

But what I want to do is only include the second class, which I gave a special name.

I've tried a few ways of doing this but here's one example that does not work but is along the lines of what I was thinking I should be able to do:

A.) First, I grab the style.css file and chuck copy/paste it into a style.scss file.

B.) Second I wrap all the whole thing in a placeholder/silent class, like so:

```
//style.scss
%placeholder {
  .one {
    color: red;
    padding-top: 1px;
  }
}
```

C.) Then I import that SCSS file and try and extend a class of my choosing that is within the placeholder, like this:

```
//style2.scss
@import "style";

.two {
  @extend .one;
}
```

When I try and compile this I get **a blank css file** (and rightly so for trying to be too tricky). The other thing I know is that you can't extend nested selectors so "@extend %placeholder .one;" is also out of the question.

**My question is this: does anyone know of a way to import and then extend a css class so that the compiled result does not include the imported css?**

The only other solution I can think of is to just delete the imported css from the top of my file before I let it out into the wild. But this is honestly less than ideal solution.

Thank you in advance to any answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using placeholders incorrectly, the placeholder should simply be `one`, no need to wrap it. Try this:

```
// style.scss
%one {
  color: red;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

// style2.scss
@import "style";

.two {
  @extend %one;
}
```

---

Note that there is an issue with this approach. While the outputted CSS is leaner than using a mixin (`@include`), you will not be able to use `%one` inside of any `@media` queries. Ie. this will not work:

```
// style2.scss
@import "style";

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .two {
    // This won't produce CSS as it's inside the media query
    @extend %one;
  }
}
```

The only way I'm aware to get around this is to use a mixin instead of a placeholder which will result in more CSS (if you use `one` more than once).

```
// style.scss
@mixin one() {
  color: red;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

// style2.scss
@import "style";

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .two {
    @include one();
  }
}
```

I've detailed the difference in output between mixins and placeholder selectors on [my blog](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/09/sass-mixins-vs-placeholder-selectors.html) if you're not aware.

Comment: Actually, `@extend` can quite often end up generating a bigger CSS file than if you used mixins (see:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/27910/26722), depending on how often the styles are being extended and the length of the selectors in question.

Comment: Ah, yeah - I was hoping there was a way to @extend my css classes and not have the old ones appear in my compiled css without changing them all to %placeholder classes. That's really what I should have asked :)

Comment: @cimmanon yea, I mentioned that. I threw a link to an article I wrote detailing the difference as well.

Comment: @Josh well yea, that's exactly the reason for the existance of placeholder selectors :P allow extending and not output the original.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to include multiple css frameworks into my project and then just extend the classes I wanted to use out of each those frameworks. It's a strange thing to want but I want it nonetheless! I guess it's more complicated than that :P

Comment: Well you could use placeholder selectors as above, just be aware of the `@media` issue.